# Georeference multiple raster layers of same area at once or identically

Tags: raster, georeferencing

I have many raster layers that I need to georeference to my existing vector layers.  Data types vary between 8 bit unsigned, 32 bit float, and bit 64 float. All have the exact same extent, cell size, and from and to areas. Is there a way to georeference all the layers at once so they all have the same RMS error? The area is complicated as we do not have roads etc. for exact points of reference.

I am using QGIS.

Comment: You mention the rasters vary by datatype, but are they all the exact same extent, origin, cell size ect? If so you could theoretically apply the same transformation from one image to all the others. If they differ, then no, you have to do them one at a time. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103878/

Comment: I ended up doing each raster layer with the same control point file as all were the exact same extent, cell size, from and to areas.  Thank you!

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107008/

Answer (score 2):

As long as all of your images share the exact same extent, origin, and cell size, they would be considered *co-registered* meaning they perfectly align to each other. In this case, yes, you can georeference one of them and then apply the exact same control points / georeferencing information / transformation to all of the remaining rasters and they should come in at the same place and with the same RMS error.

See my answer at [Georeferencing Image using saved Link Table from another Image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103878/) for a more detailed description of co-registration and why this would *not* work if the raster properties listed above weren't identical.