# Georeferencing/rectifying multiple images of different shapes and sizes at once using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing

A couple of weeks ago I georeferenced a set of 7 scanned maps (.tiffs). Although the scans all have different shapes and sizes, the outline of all the maps on there is the same, and after having georeferenced them, the maps align quite nicely.

Today I found out that the southern area should be referenced differently. The same mistake has been made for all images: the northern part is allright for all maps, but the southern boundary of my maps should be shifted upwards a bit. I don't want to do the tedious job of aligning all tiffs by hand again.

Does anybody know if there is a way to rectify them all at once? Can I relate the tiffs in some way?

Comment: Have you tried the *Auto Registration*-button on the Georeferencing toolbar? Sometimes it works well and other times not so good, but could be worth a try. At least then you only have to re-reference one of the images.

Comment: @Martin: That might work, although it is not ment for scanned maps. I cannot see to what layer I am linking here... but if I use an empty .mxd it might work :)

Comment: @artwork21: this could work, if I remove the 'white areas' along my scanned maps. I will try!

Comment: Do these maps lay on top of each other, or side by side?  If the latter you might mosaic them, then georeference the mosaic.

Comment: That would be nice, yes, but they are on top of each other. :)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question it has been marked as such of. Note this question specifically states the scans all have different shapes and sizes, so you **cannot** use the same control points from one to reference another (unless you first co-register them). The only way that would work is if after they were referenced the first time they were saved out to new files with the exact same extents/etc. Otherwise each set of georeference links must be updated independently because the transformations aren't the same. Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103878/

Answer (score 1):

If all the images will have the same adjustment, you can save the links as a text file.  When you georeference the next image, just load the link file and the image will be adjusted in the same way as the first one.

To do this, load the first image and open the georeferencing toolbar, create links to adjust the image as needed, then open the link table:

[image]

In the link table menu, you can save the links as a text file.  Once saved, you can load the next image, open the link table menu, and open the link text file you just created:

[image]